# Error When I Copy Range From Excel and Paste as Bitmap on Powerpoint

Tags: c#, excel, powerpoint

I am running the folowing C# code:

```
foreach(PictureObj pObj in this.picture_list) {
            pObj._Picture.Copy();
            slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPasteDataType.ppPasteBitmap);
            foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape s in shapes) {
                if(s._Name.Equals(pObj._Name)){
                    s.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                    s._Width = pObj._Width;
                    s._Height = pObj._Height;
                    s._Left = pObj._Left;
                    s._Top = pObj._Top;
                }
            }
        }
```

pObj._Picture propert is of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.

If I run the code on the debugger one step at a time it works but when I actualy try to run the program I get the folowing error on the PasteSpecial method:

Shapes (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.

somethimes it does paste one or two pictures before it stops, I suspect the clipboard is out of sync. If my suspicions are correct, how do I wait for the clipboard to finish doing what it needs to do?

If this is not the problem then how do I get the desire result?

Comment: Try adding a Thread.Sleep(1000) after the copy operation. Does it work then? My guess is that the copy is just not finishing quickly enough, and when you step through with the debugger the pauses give it time to catch up.

Comment: It did work but it realy took a chuck out of performance. I think there should be a clipboard event I could listen but I am not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: See the ContentChanged event here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.aspx